# Looking for the name of a short illustrated story from the 1970s/80s about a group of ladybirds that are enslaved by other insects

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, childrens-novel, illustrated-story

I'm trying to find the name of a short illustrated story from the 1970s or 1980s that was contained in a larger book.

The story is aimed at children but has an adult art style. It is very well drawn in color.

The story revolves around a group of peaceful ladybirds who live an idyllic life but one day are enslaved by another race. I think that they are also insects but I don't remember the species. Possibly black beetles.

In order to escape one of the youngest ladybirds dances to entertain her captors, she dances all day and into the night, and through to dawn and they are so entertained that they forget that dawn is the time when a giant monster known as the "one eyed hippity hop" comes out to hunt, and it devours them, freeing the ladybirds.

The illustration suggest that the monster is a small brown bird, and that they think that it only has one eye because they only ever see one side of its head.

The young ladybird is hailed as a hero but is so weak that she can barely move for the rest of her life, and ends up with all of the other ladybirds taking care of her.

Most of the story was told with plain text over illustrations.

Comment: I have never heard of a type of insect called a ladybird, but I have heard of a type of insect called a ladybug.

Comment: @M.A.Golding “Ladybird, ladybird, fly away home.  Your house is on fire.  Your children will burn.”